# Balance groups based on average, element constraints and size

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming, pseudocode

It's a complex situation, where I want to balance *groups* of numbers based on the *average* of these numbers, while keeping the *group size* unchanged and *not breaking elements constraints*.

Let me explain in detail what I mean:
[image]

I need to **switch** elements between the groups in order to **balance the group average**.
However the elements with the **same color needs to stay in the same group**, and the groups **must not change size**.

What would be a good approach for solving this problem? I'm using ***c++*** to code a matchmaking system for a game, and that's the mathematical problem I'm stuck with currently.

*My knowledge of mathematical notations are quite weak, so I would prefer some sort of **pseudo-code** as answer (if possible)*

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "balance the group average"?  In particular, I think you need to select a way to measure how imbalanced the group average is for a particular proposed solution.  What would you like to use?  The standard deviation of the group averages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [combinatorial optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization).  It is NP-hard (it is easy to see it is as hard as the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)).  Consequently, you should not expect any general problem that is efficient, scales to large problem sizes, and always returns the optimal answer.

Instead, you probably will want to use some kind of heuristics.  One approach worth considering is to use integer linear programming or some variant of it.  If your objective function is minimize the spread between largest group average and the smallest group average, then the problem can be encoded as an instance of integer linear programming (ILP) and then you could use an off-the-shelf ILP solver.  If your objective function is to minimize the standard deviation of the group averages, then the problem can be encoded as an instance of integer quadratic programming (MIQP) and then you could use a MIQP solver.  You might want to run them for a limited amount of time and use the best solution found within that time period, rather than run as long as needed to find the exact optimal solution.

The encoding of the problem as integer programming is tedious but fairly straightforward.  You introduce zero-or-one integer variables $x_{i,j}$, with the intended meaning that $x_{i,j}=1$ means that the $i$th item is assigned to the $j$th group.  (When you have multiple elements of the same color, treat them all as a single item with the same value of $i$; they just add more than one to the number of elements in that group.)  Then the number of elements in the group is a linear function of the $x$'s, and the group average of each group is a linear function of the $x$'s, so you can write down constraints for these to be a valid solution as linear inequalities.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
Yes, I think the best approach is to use some kind of heuristics, do a few iterations over it and pick the best. It's not that critical to have the groups perfectly balanced, but preferable to do some adjustments when there is a big average differential between the groups.